Asymptotic behavior of a ratio involving Bessel K functions
Consider the ratio
$$f(x) = \frac{\textrm{BesselK}^{(2,0)}(0,x)}{\textrm{BesselK}(0,x)}$$
Empirically
$$f(x) \sim \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{1.846(5) x^3} +  \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
I haven't found a good way to extract the series expansion exactly.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299999883_Higher_derivatives_of_the_Bessel_functions_with_respect_to_the_order has a formula for the second derivative of BesselK with respect to its order, but I can't make sense of it, or even simplify it for the order of 0.

Can this be written in a more common notation?

Thinking more, I would look at the series expansion of  $$\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi }}, e^x ,  K_n(x)$$

Assume that $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$. The integral representation
$$
K_\nu  (z) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - z\cosh t} \cosh (\nu t){\rm d}t} 
$$
yields
$$
\left[ {\frac{{\partial ^2 K_\nu  (z)}}{{\partial \nu ^2 }}} \right]_{\nu  = 0}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - z\cosh t} t^2 {\rm d}t} .
$$
Changing the integration variable from $t$ to $s$ via $
t = {\mathop{\rm arcosh}\nolimits} (1 + s)$ gives
$$
\left[ {\frac{{\partial ^2 K_\nu  (z)}}{{\partial \nu ^2 }}} \right]_{\nu  = 0}  = \sqrt 2 \,{\rm e}^{ - z} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - zs} \frac{{{\mathop{\rm arcosh}\nolimits} ^2 (1 + s)}}{{\sqrt {2s( 2+s)} }}{\rm d}s} .
$$
Using the series expansion
$$
\frac{{{\mathop{\rm arcosh}\nolimits} ^2 (1 + s)}}{{\sqrt {2s(2+s)} }} = s^{1/2}  - \frac{5}{{12}}s^{3/2}  + \frac{{259}}{{1440}}s^{5/2}  - \frac{{3229}}{{40320}}s^{7/2}  +  \ldots , \quad s\to 0^+,
$$
and applying Watson's lemma, we obtain
$$
\left[ {\frac{{\partial ^2 K_\nu  (z)}}{{\partial \nu ^2 }}} \right]_{\nu  = 0}  \sim \frac{1}{z}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2z}}} {\rm e}^{ - z} \left( {1 - \frac{5}{{8z}} + \frac{{259}}{{384z^2 }} - \frac{{3229}}{{3072z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $|z|\to+\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{\pi}{2}$). Since $s\mapsto \frac{{{\mathop{\rm arcosh}\nolimits} ^2 (1 + s)}}{{\sqrt {2s(2+s)} }}$ is analytic in the sector $|\arg s|<\pi$, this asymptotic expansion actually holds in the much larger sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$).
It is well known that
$$
K_0 (z) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2z}}} {\rm e}^{ - z} \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{8z}} + \frac{9}{{128z^2 }} - \frac{{75}}{{1024z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $|z|\to+\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$). Taking the ratio and expanding in negative powers of $z$, we finally obtain
$$
\frac{1}{{K_0 (z)}}\left[ {\frac{{\partial ^2 K_\nu  (z)}}{{\partial \nu ^2 }}} \right]_{\nu  = 0}  \sim \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{{2z^2 }} + \frac{{13}}{{24z^3 }} - \frac{7}{{8z^4 }} +  \ldots 
$$
as $|z|\to+\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$).

If we simply use the asymptotics of $e^x\,K_n(x)$ (have a look here); differentiate twice with respect to $n$ and finally let $n=0$
$$f(x)=\frac 1x \,\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\,\frac {a_k}{x^k}$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{13}{24},\frac{7}{8},\frac{1187}{640},\frac{155}{32},\frac{107609}{7168},\frac{1723}{32},
\frac{7189899}{32768},\frac{512875}{512},\cdots\right\}$$
More generally
$$\frac 1x+\frac{2 n^2-1}{2 x^2}+\frac{13-36 n^2}{24 x^3}+\frac{-8 n^4+68 n^2-21}{24 x^4}+$$ $$\frac{2960 n^4-12680 n^2+3561}{1920
   x^5}+\frac{256 n^6-8720 n^4+26464
   n^2-6975}{1440 x^6}$$
